# how to drive a dotstar strip from C on a raspberry pi

Tags: spi

I am trying to figure out how to drive a dotstart strip by calling write(handle, datap, len) to an SPI handle, from C, on a raspberry pi. I'm not quite clear on how to lay out the data.

Looking at https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/APA102.pdf#page=3 makes me think you start with 4 bytes of 0, a string of coded LED values (4 bytes per LED) and then 4 bytes of 1's. But that cannot be right; the final 4 bytes of 1's would be indistinguishable from a request to set an LED to full brightness white. So how could that terminate the data?

Insight welcome. Yes, I know there's a python library out there for this, but I'm coding in C++ or C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, I found the answer here:
https://cpldcpu.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/understanding-the-apa102-superled/
The end frame is more complex than the spec suggests, but the spec is correct if your string has 32 LEDS, and you must always specify values for all LEDS in your string.